# Generating instances of class in loop gives TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, oop

I've looked through a lot of replies regarding this error, however none was helpfull for my special case and since I'm new to Python, I have difficulties applying the hints to my problem.

I have a class in a file `Aheat.py` that reads

```
class Aheat():
    name = ""
    time = 0
    place = 0
    def __init__(self,name,time,place):
        self.name = name
        self.time = time
        self.place = place
```

And a file `main.py` where I want to read a html file, extract information, and create a list of objects of my class to work with them later on.

The (hopefully) essential part of my `main.py` reads

```
import urllib2
import re
from Aheat import Aheat

s = read something from url
ssplit = re.split('<p', s)  # now every entry of ssplit contains an event 
                            # and description and all the runners
HeatList = []


for part in ssplit:

    newHeat = Aheat("foo",1,1) # of course this is just an example
    HeatList.append(newHeat)
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/Workspace/ECLIPSE/running/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    newHeat = Aheat("foo",1,1)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

which is thrown when performing the second iteration.

If I take out the generation of the object of the loop, i.e.

```
newHeat = Aheat("foo",1,1)
for part in ssplit:

    HeatList.append(newHeat)
```

My code executes without a problem, but this is not what I want. I'm also not sure, if I can initialize a specific number of instances a priori, since the number of objects is estimated in the loop.

I'm using Eclipse and Python 2.7.

Comment: Are you parsing HTML with regular expressions?...

Comment: Looks like the `Aheat` class is being overwritten by a list. Are there any lines in your code that begin with `Aheat = `?

Comment: +1 @MarkR. There are modules to parse html. look at beautifulsoup https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2

Comment: Also, there is **no** context here that would give any clue regarding the source of that error.

Comment: @corn3lius, I'm aware of that, I was angling for an opportunity to post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm a mathematician and no programmer so sorry for not knowing about the problem with HTML and regex. I'm looking through beautifulsoup right now. I'm also sorry that I didn't provide the relevant context @AnttiHaapala. The comment of Kevin fixed my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regex is going to bite you.

`<p` == `<pre> || <progress> || <param> || <p> || (any user created directives on a page.)` 
follow the links in your comments to read up on why we shouldn't parse html with regex.

Thanks, @MarkR ( btw, I was only supplementing your comment and I was agreeing with you )

---

Why not put the list in your class or better yet extend list functionality with your class.

```
class AHeat(list):
    def append(self,name,time,place):
        return super(AHeat,self).append([name,time,place])


# main 
heatList= AHeat()
heatList.append("foo",1,2)
heatList.append("bar",3,4)

print(heatList[0])
print(heatList[1])

> ['foo', 1, 2]
> ['bar', 3, 4]
```

Also

Comment: Thank you, I see the problem with regex. I like the suggestion of extending the list. Thanks!